# Better Ways to Control Against Infinite Recursion

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I am wondering if there is a standard way or a better way to control against infinite recursion than in my code below? I want my recursive function to give up after max attempts. The code below does it by introducing attempt method parameter and incrementing it during the recursive invocation. Is there a better way?

```
def Rec(attempt=0):
    if attempt==10:
        return()
    else:
        print(attempt)
        Rec(attempt=attempt+1)

Rec()
```

Comment: What do you mean by **'better'**?

Comment: You could save all the previous parameters. If you get the same parameter as an earlier call, you know you've gotten into a loop.

Comment: @Barmar that only works if your function is a "pure" function ;-)

Comment: @Barmar, in this way you are not always able to control infinite recursion

Comment: @thebjorn True. And I just realized that it doesn't work for something like Fibonacci, because it calls itself twice, and one will be a repeat of an earlier one.

Comment: @Barmar it will actually work with Fibonacci, but not something like `def f(n): return random.randint(0, n)...`

Comment: @Peter Wood "better" is vague, I agree - I did not find anything with a quick googling but this feels like such a textbook example that there ought to be a "standard" solution, which I do not know.

Comment: Write a proper base case. That's how you end a recursion.

Comment: @TemporalWolf What about a recursive list iteration, when given a circular list?

Comment: Your function will always be called 10 times, it's not a max limit. There are no other exit conditions. If you want the function to be useful you need to write a base case, as @TemporalWolf says.

Comment: @PeterWood I think he's simplifying, and left out the actual recursive simplification.

Comment: What you have is similar how [intro sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort) decides when to switch to heap sort to avoid excessive recursion and worst case time complexity. In the wiki example, the caller supplies the maximum depth.

Comment: If you need to traverse a circular list, insert a sentinel object and then traverse it until you encounter your sentinel.

Comment: @Barmar you are right: this is just me illustrating my solution to the problem. Peter Wood, I did not include the main body of the function because it is not relevant, except maybe to say that it tries to do something without a guarantee of success, pseudo-randomly, and calls itself if it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yours is already good. That's the way to go. It is good because it is light weight. You basically need an `int` and a condition branch - that's it.

Alternatively you can try to guarantee to break the loop in the condition without a counter (but that usually is dependent from case to case).

Answer (score 3):

There is also this way **but is not recommended** for what you want to do - I only posted it for reference and is good to use in other cases...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 

import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5)

def Rec(attempt=0):
    print attempt
    Rec(attempt=attempt+1)

try:
    Rec()
except RuntimeError:
    print 'maximum recursion depth exceeded'
```

From [`sys.setrecursionlimit(limit)`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit)
To be even more clear, as said in python docs what `sys.setrecursionlimit(limit)` does is:

> Set the maximum depth of the Python interpreter stack to limit. This
>   limit prevents infinite recursion from causing an overflow of the C
>   stack and crashing Python.
>
> The highest possible limit is platform-dependent. A user may need to
>   set the limit higher when she has a program that requires deep
>   recursion and a platform that supports a higher limit. This should be
>   done with care, because a too-high limit can lead to a crash.

So in my opinion is not good to mess with the *Python interpreter stack* unless you know very well what you are doing.

Comment: If you're going to do this, know it applies to the entire interpreter. Make sure to set it back if you don't want to potentially bork other calls.

Comment: Yea I figured that. :)

Answer (score 3):

You could make a decorator, and then you can write your proper recursive function, with its usual exit conditions, but also impose a recursion limit:

```
def limit_recursion(limit):
    def inner(func):
        func.count = 0
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            func.count += 1
            if func.count < limit:
                result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                result = None
            func.count -= 1
            return result
        return wrapper
    return inner
```

Your code would be (with a limit of 3):

```
@limit_recursion(limit=3)
def Rec():
    print('hi')
    Rec()
```

Running:

```
>>> Rec()
hi
hi
hi
```

Comment: Note: I'm not sure how this would work in a multithreaded environment. I imagine it wouldn't work as intended (c: